# Changing a page's content in Flutter. Am I doing it (kinda) right?

Tags: flutter

so, in my Flutter app, I have a few different screens that belong in the same context. You can imagine them as subpages (think a tutorial going step by step, screen by screen with instructions).

I didn't think it'd make sense for there to be dozens of different pages like

```
 class Tutorial extends StatefulWidget {...}

 class Tutorial2 extends StatefulWidget {...}

 class Tutorial3 extends StatefulWidget {...}
```

So what I am doing currently is having just one

```
 class TutorialPage extends StatefulWidget{Widget _body;}
```

with a build method like

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return _body; }
```

And then changing that _body programatically as the user goes through the tutorial with functions

```
tutorialStart(){
 setState({_body = Scaffold(body: Center(...),
 );});
}

tutorial2(){
    setState({ _body = Scaffold(body: Center(...),
     );})
    }
```

But the thing is, I have feeling that is not a good way, or even a decent way to do this. I'm quite new to Flutter, so I'd like to know what would be a better method to go changing the content of a page without creating dozens of pages?
I hope I managed to express myself well enough for you to understand my question, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use the [pageview][1],

follow this steps:

1. Create a model of the class tutorial and then create a list of the model.
2. In page view iterate the loop of that same list.
3. on click of next button it will call the next page.

Thanks
[1]: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html